# prawn gem does not load in rails

Tags: rubygems, pdf-generation, ruby-on-rails-5, prawn

Rails version: 5.0.0.1

Ruby Version: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS xenial

I want to use prawn gem to generate pdf files. I added prawn in the gem file and ran bundle install which installed prawn.

Executing 'bundle show prawn' showed

```
/home/kapil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/prawn-2.1.0
```

If I look at Gemfile.lock, it shows

`pdf-core (0.6.1)
    pg (0.18.4)
    pkg-config (1.1.7)
    prawn (2.1.0)
      pdf-core (~> 0.6.1)
      ttfunk (~> 1.4.0)`

```
kapil@kapil-server1:~/apps/badal$ rails console
Running via Spring preloader in process 32445
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.1)
irb(main):001:0> require "prawn"
LoadError: cannot load such file -- prawn
    from /home/kapil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /home/kapil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /home/kapil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/kapil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from (irb):1

irb(main):013:0* Prawn::Document
NameError: uninitialized constant Prawn
    from (irb):13
    from /home/kapil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in `start'
    from /home/kapil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in `start'
```

My Gem file is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more:     https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

#Added by Kapil

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '~> 2.9',  :github => 'derekprior/momentjs-rails'
gem "jstree-rails-4"
gem "rails-erd"
gem "seedbank"
gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem "select2-rails"
gem "bullet", :group => "development"
gem 'activerecord-session_store'
gem "prawn"
```

I do not know why is prawn behaving in this manner?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a expert but it's look like you need to learn ruby on rails from the beginning. With `rails console` you can check what going in you DB and it's nothing to do with Gemfile. I recomment to start with [Ruby on Rails Tutorial]. Sorry mate you should do a long way to prawn.[1](https://www.railstutorial.org/book)